# Stop using a file

Tags: vb.net

first i created a file by pressing on a label then i want to be able to delete it without restarting app (because it becomes in use)

code is

```
Dim UniWinDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "UniWin Activator Data")
Dim MsgIODat = Path.Combine(UniWinDataPath, "MessageIO.dat")
If File.Exists(MsgIODat) Then
    'ERROR HERE
    File.Delete(MsgIODat)
    '''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim clrdata = MessageBox.Show("Data Cleared.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
ElseIf (Not (File.Exists(MsgIODat))) Then
    Dim nodata = MessageBox.Show("There is no data to clear.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

error: `The process cannot access the file '(PATH)' because it is being used by another process.`

i've searched and didn't find anyone talking about this in vb.net language

is there a way to let my app stop using it to delete the file?

Comment: Share the code which *makes* the file. You will almost certainly need to use the `Dispose()` method on a stream which makes the file, either directly or by using a `using` block.

Comment: ill copy and paste the exact code... see thread again

Comment: I meant the code which writes to the file - the label event handler, not the code which gets the file name.

Comment: @Wai code is file.create(path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispose the `FileStream` returned by the `File.Create()` Method.
When you create the file,

```
File.Create("file").Dispose()
```